# What is the available version of Visual Studio for DD4T project template?

Tags: dd4t, 2013-sp1

I'm setting up DD4T.

I tried to install `DD4T.1.31-MVC4-Tridion2013-VS2012-VS2013.vsix` to my Visual Studio, but it failed.

According to log message, version of Visual Studio is not available.
I tried following versions, but still it fails.

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium
- Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010
- Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
- Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Which version is available for this project template?

Is it impossible to install this project template to free Visual Studio like "Express 2012"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first thing is, Visual Studio Express Editions don't support extensions. So for sure it won't work.

By noticing the name of the vsix file, it indicate that it is for VS 2012 and 2013. So it won't work for other versions of visual studio. So it's not working for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

You can try :

1. [community Edition of VS2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs), which is based on the Professional, supports Extensions and is free for home users.
2. Demo versions of VS 2013, which comes with free one month sunscriptions.